# Progress bar form not fully loading

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I'm writing a program that can take quite a bit to load(5-30 seconds).  I'm wanting to have a form that starts with a marquee style progress bar, so that the user knows there's something being done.

```
public FrmMain()
{
     var loading = new FrmLoading();
     loading.Show();

     InitializeComponent();

     // other start up code here

     loading.Close()
}
```

Now, `loading` pops up just fine.  The problem is that the label and the progress bar show as nothing, and it almost looks like they are crashing.  I've looked into the `BackgroundWorker`, but, honestly, I don't fully comprehend how to make that work for me.  I tried to follow the tutorials and examples at:

- [BackgroundWorker Basics in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)
- [C# BackgroundWorker](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)
- [ProgressBar](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)
- [BackgroundWorker Class](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)

But my head just isn't grasping it.  Is there any other way to get the form to load properly?  Thanks for any and all help.

**EDIT**

My `BackgroundWorker` attempt included me creating a function which performed all the actions that were done in my `FrmMain`.  So, I had:

```
public FrmMain()
{
    Loading = new FrmLoading();
    Loading.Show();

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void FormLoading()
{
     // Initialize and loading elements of the form
     InitializeComponent();
}
private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    FormLoading();
}

private void BackgroundWorker1RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Loading.Close();
}
```

But I kept getting `NullReferenceException` on the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`

Comment: This is exactly the case for using a background worker.  Please show your attempts at using it with a description of what problems you had with that solution.  The general approach is simple.  The constructor shows the loading form, starts the background worker, the `DoWork` event does the long running task, and the completed event closes the loading form.  There are techincally other ways, such as using tasks, async/await, direct thread access, etc. but if you are having trouble with a BGW those will be harder, not easier, to work with.

Comment: The issue is that you are doing all the processing in the main (UI) thread. When you do that, the thread doesn't get the chance to paint the controls, and Windows thinks that your app is stuck. As @Servy just wrote, you should do your processing inside a background thread (a `BackgroundWorker` is suited for that) and then return to the main thread when finished.

Comment: Edited to show attempts at `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: See [Creating splash screen in .NET with a progress bar](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html)

Comment: The FrmMain() constructor has lost the InitializeComponent() call.  Yes, that's going to bomb.

Comment: The problem is that if I put the InitializeComponent() before the background loader, FrmMain loads and has nothing  on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An little-known or often-forgotten framework library is Microsoft.VisualBasic.  You can use it with C# apps.  Just add a Reference ... and this class.  It handles all background worker threading and the rest.

```
public class MyApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    private static MyApplication _application;

    public static void Run(Form form)
    {
        _application = new MyApplication{ MainForm = form };
        _application.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
    }

    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        this.SplashScreen = new MySplashScreenForm();
    }
}
```

Finally, change the app launch under Program.Main() from:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
   MyApplication.Run(new Form1());
```

If you aren't familiar, this class also offers more features like Single-Instance Handling that are definitely worth a look.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I am trying to incorporate a progress bar just to show up for couple of seconds. Problem is while the form loads (says Loading Report.), it does not close. It stays that way. This form with progress bar needs to load NOT when the application launches but when the user clicks a specific report. The report needs to run and while the database execution is going on, the progress bar needs to show. Thanks!

Comment: @Veena This answer is specific to app load. Google 'C# Progress Dialog' to get some good info for your need such as: http://csharpmentor.blogspot.com/2009/05/threading-modal-progress-dialog-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

Add a:

```
Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
```

after your `InitializeComponent();`.

And add:

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

Also, if you didn't subscribe to the `BackgroundWorker1DoWork` event handler in the Designer, you'll have to add:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing may not be elegant, but it accomplished what I needed.

```
public FrmMain()
{    
     InitializeComponent();

     backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

     var loading = new FrmLoading();
     loading.ShowDialog();
}

private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DbQuery();
}

private void BackgroundWorker1RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Loading.Close();
}
```

This brings up my `loading` form so that it has focus and fully loads.  Since I called the `DoWork` before I called the `ShowDialog()`, the `BackgroundWorker` continues to work.  Once `DbQuery()` is done, it calls the `BackgroundWorker1RunWorkerCompleted()`, which closes my `FrmLoading` and continues on with my program.  Thanks to everyone who posted.